# using mootool to create permenant bar at bottom

Tags: mootools

anyone know how to create a permenant bar at the bottom of the page ? example, look at http://www.italylettings.com/

Comment: i know the site is using JQuery, but the web site I am working on now is heavily using Mootool... so  have no choice but to continue using mootool to avoid any conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use CSS on a DIV no need for JavaScript:

```
#bottom-bar {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
```

**Update**

It [works for me](http://jsbin.com/esoji3).

An easy way with mootools to fade out is to use the `fade` function:

```
$("bottom-bar").fade('toggle');
```

Comment: the bar moved when u scroll up n down... also it allow to switch off using the x button

Comment: thanks joshperry.. that will do.. although it doesn't work well in IE6, at least give me some idea to start with...